# Is the ElasticSearch standard Node client safe for use with cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, typescript, elasticsearch, google-cloud-functions

I'm contacting an ElasticSearch node in some of my Typescript cloud functions on GCP. So far I've been creating my own HTTP requests. However, as the scope of the project grows, I'd like to use the official '@elastic/elasticsearch' package for convenience, especially when it comes to type checking. I am aware that you should not keep any resources open when a cloud function ends, but I've seen in the official documentation of the client that it keeps connections alive. Is there any way to disable this behaviour? Am I misunderstanding the meaning of some of this? I find the API documentation a bit opaque, and would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I am aware that you should not keep any resources open when a cloud function ends

Actually, that's not a requirement.  You can certainly keep a connection open.  The Firebase Admin SDK does this, as well as other Google Cloud SDKs.  It just shouldn't *do anything* between function invocations.  The connection will be kept alive for as long as the server instance is alive, which is a good optimization.

What you shouldn't do is *leak* resources that aren't going to be reused, as they could cause your function to run out of memory and crash eventually.